# How to solve for boolean algebra?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

> Which one of the following is the set of all atoms of $D_{78}$?
>   Select one:
>
> a. $\{1,2,3\}$
>   b. $\{6,26,39\}$
>   c. $\{2,3,6\}$
>   d. $\{1,2,3,6\}$
>   e. $\{2,3,13\}$

Could you please explain why ‘e’ would be the correct answers, I am trying to understand posets and boolean algebra.

Note  $D_{n}$ denotes the set of all positive integers which are divisors of $n$.

Comment: D78 means what?

Comment: D subscript 78 D_{n} denotes the set of all positive integers which are divisors of n.

Comment: Note that the prime factorization of $78$ is $(2)(3)(13)$.

Comment: Start with the root $1$, branching to $2,3,13$. You can build a divisor lattice from those "atoms".

Comment: why is it necessary here to have prime factorisation? Thanks

Comment: For example, from $2$ and $3$ you can get $6$, so $6$ is not an atom.

Comment: so atoms are prime numbers?

Comment: In this context, yes.

Comment: Are you using a textbook? If so, which one?

Comment: Ok thanks the textbook I am using is http://faculty.uml.edu/klevasseur/ADS2_zips/ADS_V2-0.pdf

Comment: As an aside: "Atom" comes from greek "atomos" meaning "indivisible"

Comment: @user2287434: For this question, what are the elements of the Boolean algebra? What is the bottom element? What is the top element? For this algebra, what is the definition of "join" and "meet"? Then draw the Hasse diagram. The atoms will be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$78 = 2 \times 3 \times 13$ So $78$ is square free, which makes $D_{78}$ a Boolean algebra: It means that every divisor is of the form

$$d= 2^{a}\cdot 3^{b} \cdot 13^{c}, \text{ where } a,b,c \in \{0,1\}\text{.}$$

So this Boolean algebra is just isomorphic to $\{0,1\}^3$ as a product algebra, and its atoms are the divisors corresponding to the "unit vectors" $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$ corresponding to the prime divisors $2,3$ and $13$.

Answer (score 1):

An atom is a minimal element in $D_{n}\setminus\{1\}$ (under divisibility, $1$ is the minimum element).

Thus it is an element that has no proper divisor except $1$. How do you call such numbers? Are there any in $D_{78}$?